# range.requireValuesInList and requireValuesInRange seem to be broken

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Up to this morning, the following code worked without any problems

```
function onOpen(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B100");
  var dv = range.getDataValidation();
  dv.requireValuesInList(["Shower","Shave","Shop"]);
  dv.setShowDropDown(true);
  range.setDataValidation(dv);    
}
```

But this evening, both functions give the error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function requireValuesInList in object DataValidation.
TypeError: Cannot find function requireValuesInRange in object DataValidation.
```

Any idea what happened? are these functions being replaced?

Just to test, I created a new blank spreadsheet, pasted in the onOpen function and tried to run it... no work.

Any insight is greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you print the return value of Object.keys(dv) [listing all the methods of the DataValidation object] you now get:
isAllowInvalidData,setAllowInvalidData,getCriteriaValues,setHelpText,toString,setCriteria,getCriteria

It seems the DataValidation prototype has just changed utterly, with no warning or documentation of the change. Google’s own documentation (http://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation) refers to the now-defunct DataValidation prototype.

Nice one Google!

Waqar, I’m not sure how you can claim getDataValidation() is undocumented.  The DataValidation object returned by getDataValidation() was well-documented at the link I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

getDataValidation() method in range object is undocumented so we can't say what happened to this actually. Best practice is to use only those methods and classes which are documented.

Here is a link for the same in issue tracker. You may check it.

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2356